# Move left barbutton item more to the right

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a leftbar button item. But I want it to move it more to the right. At the moment it sticks to the left hand side. Any body has an idea how I can achieve this?

Here is my code for the button itself.

```
 UIButton *button =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"task_status.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(changeStatus:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(80, 0,100, 18)];
    self.tabBarController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```

Hope anyone kan help me with this.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what I have done it worked for me

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_bar_back.png"] ;
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, -15.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);//set your button frame
[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitle:@"BACK" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 8, 0, 0);// if want to move text more towards right
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width+10, 50)];
button.center = CGPointMake(view.center.x, view.center.y);
[view addSubview:button];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:view] autorelease];

[view release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not Adding Directly rightbar Button?

```
self.tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(changeStatus:)] autorelease];
```